# Pass null as value if GET request fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, axios

I'm iterating over an array of GET requests using promise.allSettle, and some endpoints are throwing a 500 error. I need to map the responses 1:1 to another data structure, so I need the errors to somehow still pass a null value so I can still iterate over them and map them 1:1.

Is there a way to pass a null value from an error in promise.allSettle array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

```
Promise.allSettled([
  Promise.resolve(33),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(66), 0)),
  99,
  Promise.reject(new Error('an error'))
])
.then(values => console.log(values));

// [
//   {status: "fulfilled", value: 33},
//   {status: "fulfilled", value: 66},
//   {status: "fulfilled", value: 99},
//   {status: "rejected",  reason: Error: an error}
// ]
```

you will get the errors in `promise.allSettle`, so you just need to loop throught the result and map the errors to null